# Credit Card Payment Providers

Tags: credit-card

I am working with a project where consumer (user of system )have to pay with credit card (airticket). To handle credit card payments i also need to handle merchant account and card validations as well. I looked on some standard providers like Google , Amazon , Paypal . I found pay Pal Rest API for .net . But i don't know this will suit with my workflow . My workflow is (end User) have to choose his credit card and pay for ticket, then payment should be transfer to my clients account (travel agency ) . Can you please suggest some payment solution which can automatically handle merchant account,credit card Validation ,  and give response after payment  example either payment was successful or failure , less redirection to their ,site.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be probably a payment gateway. 
You can look at [Shopify Payments Gateway](http://www.shopify.com/payments) solution
Alternatively, you can check [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) or few bigger ones like [PayPal payflow gateway](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/payflow-payment-gateway). [Gate2Shop](http://try.gate2shop.com/014001apnd/?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=eng-phrase-g2s-generic-main&adgroup=payment-gateway&campaign_id=70114000002JAU8&gclid=CPac38TnuMICFY_MtAodOiUASg) or others available in your area.

Comment: Thanks indeed it helped i decided to process with paypal gateway

Comment: anonymous downvoter, burn in hell!